# How to create several spinners on one page for Android?

Tags: android, spinner

Ive seen so many tutorials on how to make spinners, but they all show just one per page. When I try to insert 2, the second one just doesnt work. I have no previous knowledge of Android programming so maybe Im just putting the second spinner code in the wrong place of something. I could really use some help with a code example please.

Ive tried 5 times but I cant seem to post my code here so far but its just a simple code for one spinner

Thank you!

EDIT: got the answer here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Spinner1.html

Comment: Actually Ive just figured it out but cant seem to be able to delete this question, sorry.

Comment: Post your answer, this will help others with the same issue, Then in a couple of days mark it as the correct answer, welcome to SO :-)

Comment: Blundell I would love to post the code but I cant figure out how...yeah Im a total noob, but I found and copied the code from here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Spinner1.html

Comment: You could even just post that link as your answer :-) looks good!

Answer (score 0):

Try This Layout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/search_scrvw"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/search_table"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dip" >

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView 
                android:text="Sex" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Spinner 
                android:id="@+id/spnr_srch_sex" 
                android:layout_width="150dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView 
                android:text="Age" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Spinner 
                android:id="@+id/spnr_srch_age" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView 
                android:text="Country" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Spinner 
                android:id="@+id/spnr_srch_country" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </TableLayout>  


  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```